# Rotation Axis Remap?

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, rotation

I am using a tracking device (only rotation tracked, not position) for input and I send its rotation matrix to an OpenGL application. The tracker sends an identity matrix when it's aligned with it's axis system, i.e when the tracker is facing towards its Y axis and the up direction of the tracker is facing it's Z axis. As seen in the right hand side of the illustration.

[image: Axis Systems Diagram]

If I rotate the tracker however, the corresponding rotation in my opengl program is wrong. To try to remedy that I tried to multiply the matrix provided by the tracker with:

```
  1  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0
  0 -1  0  0
  0  0  0  1
```

To remap but no matter what I try it seems like always one of the three rotations is wrong.

Is there some matrix that I could multiply my tracker's matrix with to get the rotations right?

===== EDIT =====

Android's remapCoordinateSystem seems to achieve what I want but I can't understand the code in there: 
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#L1459

Comment: Do you right or left multiply the tracker? Try switching the matrix multiplication operands.

Comment: You mean after you write `glRotatef(degree, axis)` you get wrong rotation or when you compute the transformation matrix manually you get it wrong?

Comment: Shahbaz: I just pass the tracker's matrix on to OpenGL as it is (via a shader). If you look at the diagram, when the device rotates about it's z axis, the opengl object I'm applying the matrix to will rotate differently.

Comment: @Jubei so you compute the matrix manually? Try, in your OpenGL program, sending this matrix: [1 0 0 0; 0 cos_a -sin_a, 0; 0 sin_a cos_a 0; 0 0 0 1] with an ever-increasing alpha. Does it still rotate wrongly?

Comment: No it doesn't rotate wrong. Even with my tracker's matrix it doesn't rotate "wrong". When my tracker rotates about Z then openGL rotates about its Z axis. It's not wrong, it's as expected, but not as desired. I need to remap the axis!

@datenwolf I muptiply as such: modelMatrix = AxisChangeMatrix*TrackerMatrix;

Comment: @Jubei what do you mean saying "It's not wrong, it's as expected, but not as desired."? Maybe you are using degrees number instead of radians?

Comment: @shahbaz I have found a function in android that does what I want to achieve but can't quite understand how it works:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#L1459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked to translate the matrix to work properly with OpenGL.

```
//orientation is the tracker's rotation matrix
orientation = glm::rotate(orientation, glm::degrees((float)M_PI/2),vec3(1,0,0));
orientation = glm::inverse(orientation);
orientation = glm::rotate(orientation, glm::degrees((float)M_PI/2),vec3(1,0,0));
```

I don't know why it worked, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using Quaternion calculations as tracker may be rotated along its current ('momental' let's say that) axes. So, the final rotation would be the summary of all the rotations made by the tracker, i think.

Or i just did not get the meaning of your "tracker" terminus =)

Comment: The tracker is being tracked in an absolute manner, not relative. So when I point the tracker to the monitor (i.e. align it with it's axis like in the right hand side of the illustration) the tracker thinks it's facing down it's y axis.

Comment: Well imagine an input device that communicates with the computer via a cable and just sends you 9 floating point numbers (a rotation matrix).

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, what I understood is that you get the rotation matrix right, but you want the rotation to happen on another axis. For example, your matrix rotates around z, but you want it to be around x.

To do that, you have many ways.

One is to do the rotations right in the first place. For example, if from your device you get that rotation should be around z, but in your program you want to map it to x, well instead of rotating around z, rotate it around x!! Something like

```
glRotatef(rot_z, 1, 0, 0);
```

So if the data you get are like this:

```
data[] = {data_about_x, data_about_y, data_about_z}
```

you will have a map like this:

```
data_map[] = {2, 0, 1}
```

When rotating you write:

```
glRotatef(data[data_map[0]], 1, 0, 0)
```

Alternatively, you could have the map the other way around, which might make more sense to you:

```
axis_map[][3] = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
```

Then write:

```
glRotatef(data[2], axis_map[2][0], axis_map[2][1], axis_map[2][2]);
```

Comment: A rotation matrix contains all 3 rotations, about x y and z. So your answer does not apply to remapping an existing matrix I'm afraid :(

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to change the existing matrix. But wait a minute, I thought you constructed the matrix, that's why I explained how to change the construction. So you just have the transformation matrix already built?